Retornar Array en PSEINT desde Funcion
hace poco estoy comenzando con PSEINT y me encontré con un problema que por más que busco no he podido resolver. ¿Es posible retornar en una función un array?
Pretendo mostrar en el programa principal un array desde la funcion "Menu", pero al ejecutar y escribir, por ejemplo, 1, 2 y 3, el resultado es 003. El array esta bien asignado, ya que, cuando lo muestro desde la función, muestra los valores correctos.
Pienso que el problema esta en que al definir la funcion, no puedo definir que el valor retorno sea de tipo array y no se como solucionarlo
Algoritmo Calcular

   Dimension recibe[3]
   recibe[3] <- Menu //Llamamos a menú para que se ejecute
   Escribir recibe[1], recibe[2], recibe[3]

FinAlgoritmo

Funcion retorno <- Menu

   Dimension array[3]
   Definir seleccion Como Entero
   Definir primer_valor, segundo_valor Como Entero


   Escribir 'Por favor seleccione una opción'
   Escribir '1 - Sumar'
   Escribir '2 - Restar'
   Escribir '3 - Salir'

   Leer seleccion
   array[1] <- seleccion
   Escribir 'Escriba el primer valor'
   Leer primer_valor
   array[2] <- primer_valor
   Escribir 'Escriba el segundo valor'
   Leer segundo_valor
   array[3] <- segundo_valor

   Limpiar Pantalla

   retorno <- array[3]

   //Escribir array[1], array[2], array[3]  Si ejecuto esta línea para conocer si array se llena correctamente, si funciona
    
FinFuncion

Versión PSEINT 20240122
Agrego: Si cambio la linea "Escribir" del pincipal a la función, el resultado se muestra correctamente, por ende, el array se esta llenando bien en la función

No creo que sea necesario definir el tipo de retorno, después de todo es pseudo código y es bastante flexible. Probaste con retorno <- array? Entiendo que al igual que en lenguajes de programación, el identificador es array, mientras que array[3] puede expresar la declaración de la variable o el 3er o 4to elemento del arreglo según si la numeración empieza por 0 o 1.

hasta donde se de PSEINT no puedo asignar que tipo retornará, esa es mi duda

Según lo que mencionan en unos hilos de PSeInt, no es posible devolver un arreglo. Sin embargo, sí sería posible pasar un arreglo por referencia y que la función acceda o modifique sus elementos.
Proceso Ejemplo
    Dimension arreglo[3];
    modificarArreglo(arreglo, 3)    
FinProceso

SubProceso modificarArreglo(arreglo, tamano)
    Para i = 1 Hasta tamano Hacer
        arreglo[i-1] = i
    FinPara
FinSubProceso

Fuentes:

https://sourceforge.net/p/pseint/discussion/2368321/thread/49ddaf75/
https://sourceforge.net/p/pseint/discussion/2368332/thread/cfb13d05/


Entiendo, entonces sería una limitante del Pseudocodigo como tal. Necesitaba retornar multiples valores al código principal y aunque se que podría inventar una alternativa, como juntar los valores en una sola cadena de texto y luego separarlas para usarlas, no es la idea realmente
